# How Google+ shows its instant uploads in built-in Android Gallery?

Tags: android, google-plus, android-gallery

What should I to make pictures from my application be visible in built-in  Android gallery and downloaded dynamically on demand?

This is somehow done for Picasa and Google+ instant uploads, but i have no ideas how to implement this for my own application?

Answer (score 1):

The Picasa support is built into the Gallery application. Google+ uses Picasa, the "instant upload" folder is actually a folder in Picasa.